# How can i change the timezone in eclipse console view without changing sistem time?

Tags: eclipse, logging, console

I want the messages logged to console use a different timezone than my normal system time. Can it by done from eclipse?

PS it says on the site that you do not have to register  to post question but it is not true apparently

Comment: The solution for me was to play with the 'run configuration' of my project. Using the -Duser.timezone=America/Arizona (you can also use quotes after the = sign) the time was properly changed. Make sure you enter it in the VM arguments textbox, not in the user arguments. Wonder what is the difference between the two